# Git: Journeying to the beginning of time and back again

Tags: git, version-control

As a relative newcomer to git, there is something that I have never quite managed to work out -- how to easily rewind and fast-forward to different points in a branch's timeline.

Today, I need to write a report which involves making screenshots from the codebase at the beginning of the git revision history and comparing it to how the program looks now. What's the easiest way to do this in git?

Comment: That's a nice title!

Comment: use "checkout" to switch to various points in your Git history, then you can use git log variations (such as --graph) to visualize how things looked at that time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ..how to easily rewind and fast-forward to different points in a branch's timeline.
>
> Today, I need to write a report which involves making screenshots from the codebase at the beginning of the git revision history and comparing it to how the program looks now. What's the easiest way to do this in git?

Going back in time with git is surprisingly easy. Suppose your history looks like this

```
hash  : commit message
======================
3q4htq: fixed bug that the new feature introduced
364572: added a new feature
44tdrt: made some more stuff
235326: made some stuff for the first time
224y4y: Initial commit
```

(commit hashes are made up)

Say you want to go back to the state the project was in at the time commit 235326 was made. All you need to do is

```
$ git checkout 235326
```

You can now view files and make your screenshots of the code. When you are ready to go back to "the future" you can simply do

```
$ git checkout master
```

or replace master with whatever branch name or commit hash you originally came from. You can use checkout command like this to 'jump around' in the project history.

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand, you want to create a patch that turns some `initial` commit, into the `final` commit.

Let's say you have a `git log` output like this:

```
* 58ef3f6 [maven-release-plugin] prepare for next development iteration
* 15ded94 [maven-release-plugin] prepare release 1.7
* 1687ba4 fix some more bugs
* 1687ba4 fix some bugs
* a4f3918 implement new feature
* c2065d1 update datasources
* 06349b5 set up external interfaces
* 723e37f branched from trunk
```

Then, to create a cumulative patch of the changes between `723e37f` and `58ef3f6` you'd do:

```
git diff 58ef3f6 723e37f
```

On the other hand, if you want to see how the code looked like at a specific point in time, you just need to checkout specific commits, e.g.:

```
git checkout 58ef3f6
```

Comment: I don't think git diff actually creates a patch, it just shows the difference in files

Comment: @TimCastelijns you can easily (depends your os) add other command to do it : `git diff 58ef3f6 723e37f | zip patch.zip -@` is what I use a lot

Comment: @TimCastelijns: Yes, It shows the differences in a format that can be applied to a specific commit with `git apply patch.txt` later. Thus it creates a patch ;-)

Answer (score 2):

If your report involves a presentation I would **highly recommend** running "[gource](https://code.google.com/p/gource/)" on your code-base (impressive eye candy!).

This tool let's you truly visualize how your graph of commits evolved over time.

Check out the "[History of Python](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cNBtDstOTmA)" gource representation.

Comment: I think its nice but if you show to management would take a lot of time to explain thats no _its not a mess_ but a structure organization of our work :)

Comment: @FredericHenri lol...maybe only developers could appreciate gource :)